# How to type annotate type annotation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I want to annotate a type annotation in `Callable` signature of a wrapper. The wrapper should accept any function that has first parameter a subclass of `A` (`funcb` in the example).

Minimal code:

```py
from typing import Callable

class A():
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def wrapper(func: Callable[[A], str]):
    pass

@wrapper # ok
def funca(self: A) -> str:
    return "a"

@wrapper # error here
def funcb(self: B) -> str:
    return "b"
```

Error:

```
Argument of type "type[]" cannot be assigned to parameter "func" of type "(A) -> str" in function "wrapper"
  Type "type[]" cannot be assigned to type "(A) -> str"
    Function return type "" is incompatible with type "str"
      "" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I tried searching on google but I can't find the correct way to describe this problem.

Comment: `Callable` is * contravariant* in the arguments.

Comment: I want to change signature of the wapper to also accept funcb.